# use reflection to get type from an interface

Tags: c#, .net, reflection

Given the following types

```
private class MyTestDummyClassValidationDef : ValidationDef<MyTestDummyClass>
    {
        ...
    }

public class ValidationDef<T> : IValidationDefinition<T>, IConstraintAggregator, IMappingSource where T : class        
{        }

public interface IMappingSource
{
    IClassMapping GetMapping();
}

public interface IClassMapping
{
    Type EntityType { get; }
    ...
}
```

At configuration time I know all of the ValidationDefinitions; "MyTestDummyClassValidationDef " above is an example of such a definition.

If you follow the inheritance / implementation trail, at the end is an EntityType that is exposed by IClassMapping.

As part of my validation infrastructure, various objects may be asked to validate themselves. The objects may or may not have a ValidationDef defined for them, either because validation doesn't apply fo that object or the definition hasn't been written yet. If an object is asked to validate itself and there is no definition then a runtime error will occur.

SO, what I am trying to is have a list of EntityTypes that I can use to check at runtime. If the object being asked to validate itself is not on the list then I can avoid the runtime error that would otherwise occur.

How might I do that?

Cheers,
Berryl

## the code I was looking for

```
public EntityValidator(ValidatorEngine validatorEngine, IEnumerable<Type> defTypes) {

ValidationDefs = new List<Type>();
foreach (var type in defTypes) 
{
    if (type.BaseType.GetGenericTypeDefinition() != typeof(ValidationDef<>)) continue;

    var mappingSource = (IMappingSource) Activator.CreateInstance(type);
    var entityType = mappingSource.GetMapping().EntityType;
    ValidationDefs.Add(entityType);
}
```

Comment: Can you elaborate a little bit more?

Comment: `ValidationDef<T> : IValidationDefinition<T>` -- be consistent; choose to abbreviate or choose not to.  Don't choose both.

Comment: Been reading and rereading your question for almost 10 minutes straight now and I still can't get what are you asking. Please, try to rephrase it.

Comment: @KirkWoll. That class is actually from the open source NHibernate Validator project, and not really relevant for this exercise in any event. I would imagine the authors would love to hear your code review though :--)

Comment: @L.B. I rewrote the question, let me know if it makes more sense.

Comment: @NikolaAnusev. I rewrote the question, let me know if it makes more sense.

Comment: @L.B: I'm afraid I seem to understand your question less than before (when I posted my answer) after the update. What do you mean by *there is no definition*? Why should a `MyValidationDef` class (which presumeably inherits from `ValidationDef<T>`) not implement `IMappingSource`? It inherits that interface.

Comment: @Berryl So at runtime, you want to be able to find all implementations of `ValidationDef<T>` (perhaps in some specific assembly) and create a list of values of their `EntityType` properties? Is that right?

Comment: @O.R.Mapper. Yes, of course you are correct. Objects which are not known as EntityTypes may be asked to validate themselves; this is what I mean by the have no definition. I, umm, rewrote it again. Sorry for the confusion.

Comment: @Berryl Ok, glad that I finally get it! :) Just a moment, I'll write an answer for you.

Comment: @O.R.Mapper `I'm afraid I seem to understand your question less than before`  This question: `Can you elaborate a little bit more?` ? :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, after clarification (see comments to the question), here is the way to find all implementations of ValidationDef in an assembly and create a list of values of their EntityType properties:

```
List<Type> entityTypes = new List<Type>();

foreach (Type type in Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().GetTypes())
{
    if (InheritsFromValidationDef(type))
    {
        IMappingSource mappingSource = (IMappingSource)Activator.CreateInstance(type);
        entityTypes.Add(mappingSource.GetMapping().EntityType);
    }
}

private static bool InheritsFromValidationDef(Type type)
{
    Type baseType = type.BaseType;
    bool result = baseType != null && 
                  baseType.IsGenericType &&
                  baseType.GetGenericTypeDefinition() == typeof(ValidationDef<>);
    return result;
}
```

Few points to note here:

- Types in the current assembly are being examined (`Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly`). Obviously, this may or may not be sufficient for your scenario.
- `BaseType` returns the direct parent of the type being examined. Again, you may want to examine the type hierarchy a bit further up the inheritance chain.
- It is assumed that all examined types have a parameterless constructor. Otherwise, `Activator.CreateInstance` bit won't work.

Although it is certainly possible to do what you ask, I would like to **strongly emphasize** that it is very likely that there is much, *much* simpler solution to your validation needs. From what you've told us of your solution, it is obvious that it has a few serious flaws:

- How is it possible that you can invoke validation on objects that cannot be validated? I think that this is the root of all your sorrows.
- Your inheritance hierarchy is far too complex and hard to understand. Why do you need so many interfaces?

Perhaps try to create a separate question detailing your validation needs. I am sure that a simpler solution can be found.

Comment: The `BaseType` comparison will return `false` if there is any type argument set for the type. A closed generic type does not inherit from its generic type definition (which can be retrieved with `Type.GetGenericTypeDefinition`). Also, if the inheritance relationship is indirect, you may want to use the `Type.IsSubclassOf` method rather than a direct equality comparison to `Type.BaseType`.

Comment: @Nikola Anusev. The O.R.Mapper was quite correct about the bug in your code; please correct it so I can award you the answer in good conscience, and thanks for helping me out on this (I left some working code at the end of my question). Cheers

Comment: @Nikola Anusev. Yeah, sometimes getting it simple takes a very complex course!! The good news is I have a powerful validation framework that knows how to play with NHibernate and not pollute my POCOs. And I have a super type in my presentation layer that invokes validation using IDataErrorInfo. The bad news is I had to do something nasty like this to fine tune everything, which is better, for now, than rewriting the entire architecture. Cheers

Comment: Thanks for that, I've fixed it. @Berryl, I wish you luck with your solution - although from my experience, complex solutions like this are not worth the effort and maintenance gets really difficult over time.

Answer (score 1):

If I understand this correctly, you want to call an explicit interface implementation of a method, i.e. a method that implements an interface method and that is only visible in the interface itself, not in the class.

In order to do so, first retrieve the `Type` object for `IClassMapping` (with `typeof(IClassMapping)`). On that object, call `GetProperty` to retrieve a `PropertyInfo` instance for the `EntityType` property.

You should then be able to retrieve the property value by invoking `PropertyInfo.GetValue` on your `ValidationDef<T>` instance.

Use, for example, this method:

```
Type GetEntityType(ValidationDef<T> def)
{
    PropertyInfo prop = typeof(IClassMapping).GetProperty("EntityType");
    return (Type)prop.GetValue(def, null);
}
```